# How to have a limited set of users on Office365/Google Apps and balance on vanilla Postfix

Tags: postfix, g-suite, google, microsoft-office-365

As the mail heading suggests, we have about 100 mail users, we would like to move about 15 users on to one of the cloud based services Office 365 or Google Mail. Balance we would like them to continue with the current e-mail infrastructure which is a Postfix based mail server. The domain name must be the same. Is there a way to load balance between these users?

That is
1)a1@xyz.com can be on Office 365 while a2@xyz.com may be on a vanilla postfix installation.
2) There should not be mail bounces. System must be smooth.

Comment: '2) No mail bounces.  System must be smooth' is a redundant and slightly insulting request.  Might be why you got downvoted.  Obviously it should be smooth and mail should be delivered, not bounced...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a pretty straightforward walkthrough for this.

The nomenclature here is "SMTP namespace sharing" and Exchange Online (Office 365) can do this.

Typically the idea is to "test out" Office 365, but it will still work long term as well if you so desire.

The full walkthrough can be found here: [Pilot Office 365 with a few email addresses on your custom domain](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Pilot-Office-365-with-a-few-email-addresses-on-your-custom-domain-39cee536-6a03-40cf-b9c1-f301bb6001d7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

> You can pilot Office 365 by moving just a few people to Office 365,
>   keeping the rest of your staff on your existing email system.
>   **Everyone’s email can use one custom domain name, whether they get
>   their email using Office 365 or your existing email provider.**

I won't quote the entire article...it's on the Office365.com site link above and won't be going away so you can go there instead of reading a wall of markdown here.

Comment: This precisely what I was looking for

Comment: *"I won't quote the entire article...it's on the Office365.com site link above and won't be going away so you can go there instead of reading a wall of markdown here."* It has gone away...

Comment: @peteroffice thank you...I'll update the article with the new Support article link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Pilot-Office-365-with-a-few-email-addresses-on-your-custom-domain-39cee536-6a03-40cf-b9c1-f301bb6001d7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can achieve that is to have a local account or alias `a1@xyz.com` and forward it to a second account `a1@xyz-ext.com` handled by Office365/GApps.

This only works if you can set up  these services to send mails as coming from `xyz.com` even if they only receive for `xyz-ext.com`, and I don't know if they offer this.

All in all, this is a kind of fragile setup. Why would you want to do this? Alsom I don't understand what you mean by "load balancing" in this context.

Comment: This is correct, and is the system described in TheCleaner's link.